# Why I can't move a Path in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, path, shapes

I tried to move (hold the left mouse button and drag) a `UIElement` on a `Canvas` in Wpf.

It worked for a `Rectangle` but when I tried the same to a `Path` shape it does not move.

Here is **the layout**, just 2 elements inside a canvas:

```xml
<Canvas Background='Beige'
            Name='canvas'>
        <Rectangle Width='50'
                   Height='50'
                   Fill='LightPink'
                   Canvas.Left='350'
                   Canvas.Top='175'
                   MouseMove='OnMouseMove'
                   Name='square' />

        <Path Fill="Cyan"
              Stroke="Black"
              MouseMove='OnMouseMove'>
            <Path.Data>
                <GeometryGroup>
                    <EllipseGeometry Center="20, 40"
                                     RadiusX="20"
                                     RadiusY="40" />
                    <EllipseGeometry Center="20, 40"
                                     RadiusX="10"
                                     RadiusY="30" />
                </GeometryGroup>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
```

And here is the **code-behind**:

```cs
private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Source is Shape shape)
            {
                if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                {
                    Point p = e.GetPosition(canvas);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(shape, p.X - shape.Width / 2);
                    Canvas.SetTop(shape, p.Y - shape.Height / 2);
                }
            }
        }
```

The `Path` is a `Shape` like the `Rectangle` and `OnMouseMove` is executed for both controls.

Why only the `Rectangle` is moving and the `Path` isn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ActualWidth and ActualHeight instead. Width and Height, if you check, are NaN.

Comment: Do you know why the Path's Width/Height were 0 and the rectangle's not?

Comment: @Themelis Width and Height are properties you set explicitly (sometimes). Generally you do NOT set them so the thing can be sized based on the content. In the case of the rectangle, you set them explicitly. For the path, you didn't... its implied by the stuff inside of it. Thus Width/Height will be NaN and the real sizes will be in Actual*… you should NEVER use Width/Height for UI calculations. Always use Actual* to consider scaling, transformations and other factors like size to content setups.

Comment: Thanks that helps